# Visual Studio runs comments

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

For some reason VS 2013 is completely ignoring my changes to the file.

Namely, even if I comment a whole section out it would still execute it! 
[image]

I tried:

- Clean build
- restart computer
- removing and including the same file again

Note: I am developing a cross platform application using Xamarin and VS.

Would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: Reinstall Visual Studio ....

Comment: For starters, do delete project's bin and obj folders. and run it again. Once compiled you might also disassemble the assembly to check whether the code is included or not (I doubt it).
If this doesn't work then try manually deleting the application on your device.

Comment: Thanks @MihaMarkic, I tried doing that but no luck. I will try and reinstall VS as some other strange things are happening. For instance I can only open the solution from file-> recent projects and solutions... if I try opening it from somewhere else VS crashes. Keep everyone updated in case they have similar problems.

Comment: Still have the problem, other solutions are absolutely fine but not this one. I reinstalled VS just in case but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this question or answer would help anyone but here goes...

**Solution:** I had to update my SDK from the Android SDK Manager:

1. Open Android SDK Manager
2. Under Tools tick the checkbox next to the most recent Rev. ( I installed 23.0.5)
3. Click "Install packages..."

**Background**

After having the problem I described I noticed few other really strange things. For example VS would not let me modify any of my drawables. If I tried to delete, add or rename any drawable VS would get stuck and the only way to solve this was to force stop it.

Here is the bug for this issue [Visual Studio hangs when including, excluding, or saving files in Android resource folders](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18452).

Once I installed the latest SDK everything was well.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have compiled the project for Release, change that to Debug and build it again.

Comment: Did you check your Manifest.xml? Maybe you set there debuggable to false.